# why datepicker is not working in angularJs code?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
angular.element(document).find("#bidValidDateEdit").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    maxDate: $scope.evntDate,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: false,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
    nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

I used angular.element() and also I tried with jQuery() but still its showing error. I am trying dual mode where running angulejs code and angular 5 code side by side
[errorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iF4l.png)

[image]

> TypeError: angular.element(...).find(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Don't post images of code or errors (as mentioned in the help -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: Well, `datepicker` is introduced by the jQuery UI library, not jQuery itself, so you need to have a reference to that library included in your HTML before that code runs.

Comment: yes its working now thanks